# c# changing specific index location within a 2 dim string array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, console-application, type-2-dimension

`

```
string[,] Board = new string[10, 11];
         int i;
            int x;

            Console.WriteLine("  ¦ A B C D E F G H I J");
            Console.WriteLine("--+--------------------");
            for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                if(Row != 9)
                Console.Write((i + 1).ToString() + " ¦ ");
                else
                    Console.Write((i + 1).ToString() + "¦ ");
                for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(Board[j, i] + "# ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
```

I would like to change the "# " at row 4 and column 5 with an "X ".

I tried the code:  array[4, 5] = "X ";

but when I run the program it does not reassign the "# " at row 4 column 5 to "X "

I'm not sure what I doing wrong with the line: array[4, 5] = "X ";

I tried the code:       Board.SetValue("X ", int.Parse((Board[4, 5])));

but even that will not change the  # in that one location to an "X" while leaving the rest as #

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine, as long as you assign `Board[4,5]` prior to running the printing loop. [Demo](https://ideone.com/HplPdb)

Comment: http://rextester.com/TNTH67912 yep, maybe your problem is understanding what are zero based indexes. (Array uses them)

Comment: Note that your code uses column, row and not row, column

Comment: I believe there is some confusion.  The for loop is initially assigning each value to #.  I want to then change a specified location to and "X"

Comment: you know you'll have to print it out again, right? If you change your array, it won't change what you already printed.